# urdf_spawner -J option not working as intended

Tags: gazebo, rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I want to set the initial joint positions of a robot in gazebo simulator starting with paused physics. I used the following in the launch file.

```
  <node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" respawn="false" output="screen"
        args="-urdf -model ps -param robot_description -J joint1 1.5 -J joint2 0.75 -J joint3 -0.5"/>
```

also I tried,

```
<node pkg="rosservice" type="rosservice" name="resetter"
                args="call --wait /gazebo/set_model_configuration '{model_name: ps, urdf_param_name: robot_description, joint_names: [joint1, joint2, joint3], joint_positions: [1.5, 0.75, -0.5]}'" />
```

without the -J option in urdf_spawner. Neither seems to work. Currently I have not implemented any controllers for the joints. Therefore, disabling controllers as in [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/10999/initialize-pr2-posture-in-gazebo/) need not be considered for the time being. I could see the following messages but still the joint angles have not changed.

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1397641007.444278] [0.000000] Waiting for service /gazebo/set_model_configuration
[INFO] [WallTime: 1397641007.445439] [0.000000] Calling service /gazebo/set_model_configuration
[INFO] [WallTime: 1397641007.446698] [0.000000] Set model configuration status: SetModelConfiguration: success
```

The only way I could get it to work is by calling:

```
rosservice call /gazebo/set_model_configuration '{model_name: ps, urdf_param_name: robot_description, joint_names: [joint1, joint2, joint3], joint_positions: [1.5, 0.75, -0.5]}'
```

separately before I unpause physics.

I use ROS-Hydro with Gazebo 1.9

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/153596/urdf_spawner--j-option-not-working-as-intended/) by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 387 on 2014-04-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/cafce361678b82ece059785ba91f1b8fbc1ef48c/gazebo_ros/scripts/spawn_model) of `urdf_spawner`.`spawn_model` today, the way you pass arguments seems fine. I suggest you open an issue at [the issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/).

Also recently you can pass them via parameter. See https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/301

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0